# Should comfrey be a companion of blueberries?

Tags: blueberries, companion-planting, comfrey

I have access to a lot of free comfrey, and was wondering if it would be a bad idea to plant comfrey around the blueberry bushes to get them more nutrients easily.

Answer (score 6):

No. It's not a great companion for anything as a growing plant because it grows rapidly and takes up a lot of nitrogen and minerals from the soil as it does. Precisely because it does that,  though,  Comfrey leaves have their uses; they're often used to make a sort of tea (or sludge, depending) to use as home made fertlizer, or as a 'green manure/mulch' using chopped up leaves, more info here

http://permaculturenews.org/2010/10/01/the-wonderful-multi-purpose-comfrey-plant/

Comment: Agreed. Planting comfrey as "companion" is a bad idea.

Comment: wouldn't comfrey be pulling nitrogen to the surface for the blueberries, then putting it back into the same soil?

Comment: If you ever need bumble bees, though, comfrey sure attracts them (at least ours does here in southwestern Idaho).

Comment: @blackthumb - no, it won't, it'll be sucking it all in and keeping it to itself,all the time its got roots in the soil.

Comment: @Shule - yep, very valuable for bees in early spring here too

Comment: If bringing nutrients to the surface via chop-and-drop style gardening, then would the blueberry then have greater access to those nutrients or does the blueberry already go to the depth of the comfrey?